# when application zoom the application processing speed is getting too slow

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfviewer, zooming

we have developed PDF application using Javascript with include of many controls like Dialog, Splitter, Text box, Drop down.

When we zoom the PDF document once PDF loaded in the application other control speed getting too slow.

#### For example Zoom the document above 400%. Now dialog open and close is getting strucked and hanged.

Can you please suggest me - why controls getting hanged after zooming. There is an issue in zooming code or any other else?